# Styling dynamically created html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a search in page function with javascript. I was looking at [this script](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm).

It is creating the input element dynamically inside an iframe to skip the text in the search input box. I have bootstrap running on my project and the dynamic content doesn't get the bootstrap styling. How can I style the input box and submit button with bootstrap?

Comment: Link the stylesheet in iframe's head.

Comment: @Oriol that removes the button. http://jsfiddle.net/uorvvdd6/

Comment: I would also like to know if there is a way to it other than including inside the head because this is going on a wordpress site and all the css styles are enqueued.

Comment: The iframe was too short: http://jsfiddle.net/uorvvdd6/1/

Comment: @Oriol That was silly of me. Thanks (Y)

Comment: I am not sure how it works but the jsfiddle looks like it includes bootstrap css. see the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uorvvdd6/2/), notice the green submit button

Comment: I think the easier and better approach is to simply not use the iframe.  The script you reference is very old (antique by web-standards) and you should update it anyway.

Comment: @jme11 well is there any other option out to there to do exactly the same? I mean i found others and they all highlight but they dont jump to the search result.

Comment: Understood, and I don't know the full context of what you're trying to accomplish. My point was that the way that script is written, it ignores Opera; Firefox support maybe removed at any time (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=672395); and the MSIE implementation is based on a proprietary approach that has been superseded with the standards approach since IE9.  I don't know another option offhand that would jump to the result (except CMD/CTRL+F).  Is that your requirement? Does it need to jump to every instance or just the first?

Comment: @jme11 I agree. Every instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use their respective id to style them(Hope you use firebug to inspect the webpage and get element details)

Ex: `form#f1 input[type="text"] { backgroud-color:#222222 !important;}`